# List of all available options on configuring service in Symfony2

Tags: symfony

i start work with symfony2

Now i write configs in .yml files and use constructions like this

```
services:
    my_mailer:
        # ...

    email_formatter_manager:
        class:     EmailFormatterManager
        # ...

    email_configurator:
        class:     EmailConfigurator
        arguments: ["@email_formatter_manager"]
        # ...
```

It's ok. The question is - where i can find list of all available option for describing service?

Yep, i fond source of **Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Definition** and i understand that i can get list from setters. But i still hope to find man page with review for this params. Can anybody help with link?

Thanks

Comment: I have never found a single summary list.  Sounds like a good documentation project.  This does describe all the various features: http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dependency_injection/index.html though I suspect you have already seen it.

Comment: Ep, of course the most useful were http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dependency_injection/advanced.html

Comment: Do you mean get a list of all the available services? If so, you can use `app/console container:debug`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Symfony commands to get a list of all available Bundles, and then drill-down to get both their default configuration (if defined) and their current configuration.  For example:

**Lists all of the bundles:**

```
# can also use config:debug (or debug:config in Symfony 2.6 or later)
php app/console config:dump-reference
```

**Lists the default configuration for a bundle:**

```
php app/console config:dump-reference WebProfilerBundle
```

**Outputs:**

```
# Default configuration for "WebProfilerBundle"
web_profiler:
    toolbar:              false
    position:             bottom
    intercept_redirects:  false
```

**Lists the current configuration for a bundle:**

```
# Symfony <= 2.6
php app/console config:debug WebProfilerBundle

# Symfony 2.6+
php app/console debug:config WebProfilerBundle
```

**Outputs:**

```
# Default configuration for "WebProfilerBundle"
web_profiler:
    toolbar: false
    intercept_redirects: false
    position: bottom
```

In Symfony 2.6 and above, the main command switched to `debug:config`, but `config:debug` is set as an alias so that still works.

Comment: In real i'm interested not in bundles list or their options. I'm seeking all available options for declaring my own service ( for example ) -- Bundles options specified on their pages but system options does not

Comment: Ah okay, I guess I'm trying to figure out what you mean exactly.  Do you mean just a generic list of all services that exist within your application?

Answer (score 1):

You can take a look at the xsd of the services.xml where is described every syntax of the structure (with yml differ only in how you describe not in the function).
As example you see samething like this for available key for service:

```
  <xsd:complexType name="service">
    <xsd:choice maxOccurs="unbounded">
      <xsd:element name="file" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" />
      <xsd:element name="argument" type="argument" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
      <xsd:element name="configurator" type="configurator" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" />
      <xsd:element name="call" type="call" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
      <xsd:element name="tag" type="tag" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
      <xsd:element name="property" type="property" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
    </xsd:choice>
    <xsd:attribute name="id" type="xsd:string" />
    <xsd:attribute name="class" type="xsd:string" />
    <xsd:attribute name="scope" type="xsd:string" />
    <xsd:attribute name="public" type="boolean" />
    <xsd:attribute name="synthetic" type="boolean" />
    <xsd:attribute name="synchronized" type="boolean" />
    <xsd:attribute name="lazy" type="boolean" />
    <xsd:attribute name="abstract" type="boolean" />
    <xsd:attribute name="factory-class" type="xsd:string" />
    <xsd:attribute name="factory-method" type="xsd:string" />
    <xsd:attribute name="factory-service" type="xsd:string" />
    <xsd:attribute name="alias" type="xsd:string" />
    <xsd:attribute name="parent" type="xsd:string" />
  </xsd:complexType>
```

Available [at this link](http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services/services-1.0.xsd)